# I have an "inflate exception" error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, inflate-exception

I've modified the XML code but it is still error:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity"/>
```

and this is the java code..

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);


        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        words.add(0, "one");
        words.add(1, "two");
        words.add(2, "three");
        words.add(3, "four");
        words.add(4, "five");
        words.add(5, "six");
        words.add(6, "seven");
        words.add(7, "eight");
        words.add(8, "nine");
        words.add(9, "ten");





        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);



        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);





        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


    }
}
```

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class GridViewView

I've change to ListView, but it is still exist.

Please give some solution, I'm in Udacity Android course.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Try clean the project using ListView

Comment: Out of interest - are all those dimensions used defined and valid?

Answer (score 1):

I recreate your project with the same code, and the only thing a changed was the paddings of your xml file.
Have a look:

Java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        words.add(0, "one");
        words.add(1, "two");
        words.add(2, "three");
        words.add(3, "four");
        words.add(4, "five");
        words.add(5, "six");
        words.add(6, "seven");
        words.add(7, "eight");
        words.add(8, "nine");
        words.add(9, "ten");

        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    }
}
```

XML (with modification):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity"/>
```

I had this result on simulator:

[Image_Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2YIt.png)